# 日本語に違和感: プライベートベータなサイトを未ログインユーザーで見たときのメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: あと数日日間]

1. 「あと数日日間」→「あと数日間」
2. 「電子メール」→「メール」
3. 「エリア51のサイト提案」というものは日本語SOに関してはないので、言い換えか削除が必要

一度ログインしたことのあるブラウザでも、一回だけこの画面が一瞬出たことがありました。

Answer (score 1):

文書は「警告:現在このサイトは少なくとも $daysLeft$ 日間**プライベート ベータ**です。」でしたが、「$daysLeft$」が「あと数日」になったため、「後数日 日間」になっていました。

「警告:現在このサイトは少なくとも $daysLeft$ 日間**プライベート ベータ**です。」に更新しましたが、改めて確認した方が良いかもしれません。